# Python Package Paths :: Finding Directories that Should Be .py Files

Tags: python, django

As I work through the Django tutorials, I like to see with my own eyes the `module` and `class/attribute` that I am inheriting via import by going to the source code at Github.

However, and I have attached pics to illustrate that I (think) I went to the right place, but the files seem to be missing.

1. For example, in Django tutorial Part 1:

`from django.conf.urls import include, url`

So I go to Github django code and I find:

`django/django/conf/urls`

What I find is that urls is a directory with only files : `__init__.py`, `i18n.py` and `static.py`.

There is no `urls.py` file which might have `url()` or `include()` methods.

Same with `models.Models`.

2. `from django.db import models`

On django Github site I follow the directories...

`django/django/db/models`  models is a directory, not a file with a class `Model()`

So, what am I missing here?

Looking forward to a few bread crumbs :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the source of module `foo.bar`, it can be one of the two:

- `foo/bar.py`
- `foo/bar/__init__.py`

Also note that often upper-level modules re-export selected names imported from deeper-down modules: a name may be merely imported, not otherwise defined; e.g. `django.db` does a lot of this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll dig deeper into db.